# Error in classification report test set for machine learning with SVM in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I split the data into test and train sets both of which have the target values '0's and '1's. But after fitting and predicting with SVM the classification report states that there are Zero '0's in the test sample which is not true.

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
data = load_breast_cancer()
df = pd.DataFrame(data = data['data'],columns=data['feature_names'])
x = df
y = data['target']
xtrain,xtest,ytrain,ytest 
= train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.3,random_state=42)
```

As you can see below, the test has 0s and 1s but the support in the  classification report states that there aren't any 0s!

!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2uUM.png)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the `train_test_split()`. It just states your SVM didn't predict any 0's. I assume something went wrong during the training. Can you share your code and maybe the data?

Comment: You need to show how you trained it, otherwise, it's very hard to figure out what is happening.

Comment: I have edited the code now. It's the breast cancer dataset from sklearn datasets. The rest of the training code is in the image and that's it! Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(It is **always** a good idea to include your relevant code in the example, and **not** in images)

> the classification report states that there are Zero '0's in the test sample which is not true.

This is because, from your code in the linked image, it turns out that you have switched the arguments in the `classification_report`; you have used:

```
print(classification_report(pred, ytest)) # wrong order of arguments
```

which indeed gives:

```
             precision    recall  f1-score   support

    class 0       0.00      0.00      0.00         0
    class 1       1.00      0.63      0.77       171

avg / total       1.00      0.63      0.77       171
```

but the correct usage (see the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html)) is

```
print(classification_report(ytest, pred)) # ytest first
```

which gives

```
             precision    recall  f1-score   support

    class 0       0.00      0.00      0.00        63
    class 1       0.63      1.00      0.77       108

avg / total       0.40      0.63      0.49       171
```

along with the following warning message:

> C:\Users\Root\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\classification.py:1135:
>   UndefinedMetricWarning: Precision and F-score are ill-defined and
>   being set to 0.0 in labels with no predicted samples.   'precision',
>   'predicted', average, warn_for)

because, as already pointed out in the comments, you predict only 1's:

```
pred
# result:
array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

the reason of which is another story, and not part of the current question.

Here is the complete reproducible code for the above:

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer

X, y = load_breast_cancer(return_X_y=True)
xtrain,xtest,ytrain,ytest = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.3,random_state=42)

from sklearn.svm import SVC
svc=SVC()
svc.fit(xtrain, ytrain)
pred = svc.predict(xtest)

print(classification_report(ytest, pred))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I will keep your suggestions in mind for the next time!! :D